# How to unit test DAOs without ORM

Tags: java, unit-testing, jdbc, junit, mocking

I am writing a JAX-RS web service right now. My database logic has been compartmentalized into DAO interfaces (e.g. `interface ItemDAO` and concrete implementation `class JDBCItemDAO`), which are injected into my controllers via Dependency Injection. Right now, it is relatively simple to unit test my controllers by giving them mock DAOs. However, I can not really test my DAOs because they use the JDBC API, and don't have any dependencies, other than a `ConnectionFactory` (returns java.sql.Connection to callers). I can't really just pass a mock Connection to the DAO because just verifying the SQL query that was in the DAO isn't enough. I want to be able to test that it works in the database. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The same way your would test a DAO that uses an ORM (where you also want to test that the queries actually work on the database): you populate a test database with known test data, then call your DAO methods, then check that they return or update the expected data. Tools to make the first step easier exist: DbSetup (shameless plug), DBUnit, and probably others.

Comment: Tests against a real database are usually called _integration tests_ because they no longer test a single unit of code.

Comment: @MickMnemonic however I am basically just testing my DAO objects, not any other code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set up a database. If you write standard SQL without depending on database-specific features you can use an in-memory database like [H2](http://h2database.com/html/main.html).
2. Set up `DataSource` object pointing to your database. This is preferable to `ConnectionFactory` you have right now in DAOs. You don't want to establish new physical connections all the time as this is expensive.
3. Use a pooled `DataSource` in your production code e.g. [HikariCP](https://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/) and maybe use something simplier in your test code e.g. [SingleConnectionDataSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/SingleConnectionDataSource.html)

Comment: My ConnectionFactory is actually my own object, and does return pooled connections from the database

Comment: It's not easy to write a good pool, see https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Pool-Analysis.